# computing probability ssrw

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(S_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a simple symmetric or asymmetric random walk with $S_0 =0$ and $S_{n}^* = \max_{m\leq n} S_m$. Assume that $n$ and $a$ are even positive integers, $b$ is an even integer, $b \leq a \leq n$, $2a-b \leq n$.

How can I compute $P(S_{n}^* < a, S_n = b)$?

I'm having trouble understanding what the computation means and how I would go about it.

Comment: The question is, what's the probability that your random walk ends up at $b$ at time $n$ without having reached the level $a$.  You will want to look up the *reflection principle*.